# "Converting" XHTML 1.0 Strict to HTML5

Tags: xhtml, html, xhtml-1.0-strict

OK folks,

So I have a valid XHTML 1.0 Strict webpage. I'm aware of the differences between XHTML and HTML, but, what are the differences between XHTML and HTML ***5***?

Would a 'conversion' be as easy as changing the Doctype, and it would all still validate OK?

Or, are there markup differences that would need to be changed first?

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: Just so you're aware, there's an XHTML version of HTML 5 too, though I'm not sure what version number they're giving it.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize [this post](http://oli.jp/2009/html5-structure4/) and [this post](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-boilerplates/)...

All you need to do to start taking advantage of the benefits of HTML5 is to convert your doctype from XHTML to HTML5. HTML5 is compatible with XHTML.

If you want to introduce new HTML5 tags, you will also want to add a polyfill like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) so that Internet Explorer can figure out how to render the new HTML5 elements.